# When i am entering the IP address in my postman i am getting data in the postman from my api?

Tags: mysql, node.js, api, postman

When I am entering the IP address in my postman I am getting data in the postman from my API but it is not showing any messages in my VS code console like this `"GET /newmealschedule?date=2018-10-23&id=468 200 9.100 ms - 65"` earlier it was showing.

How can I fix this any help Please However data is updated in the postman but no message is being shown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You removed [morgan](https://www.npmjs.com/package/morgan). Require it again and put this at some point in the start of your code

```
    const app = express();
    app.use(morgan('dev'));
```

Now that being said, welcome to stackoverflow. Be aware that SO is not a code on demand platform, and that you need to provide an explanation and code of what you have tried so far. I see that you have been quite active the last couple of days asking questions, but please try to resolve your problems before asking them on here. In your case, given the questions you've asked, look into express tutorials online. You seem to have bitten off more than you can chew on this project.

Comment: yes i tried it it is given data in the browser also when i am putting the address there and yes i will follow the express tutorials

Comment: I'm 99% sure that it is because `app.use(morgan('dev'))` is not being run, but without code samples it is hard to help you.

Comment: Did it solve your problem? If it did, remember to mark answers as correct